# For which polynomial roots does naively solving for $x$ give a convergent iterative method?

Tags: polynomials, roots, fixed-point-theorems

In the "The Treatise of Chord and Sine" [Jamshid al-Kashi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jamshid_al-Kashi) would calculate the unconstructable number $\sin(1^\circ)$
by using the constructible number $\sin(3^\circ)$. He used an iterative method derived from the used the trigonometric identity $\sin (3\theta) = 3\sin(\theta)-4\sin(\theta)^3$, which is equivalent to finding the roots for $4x^3-3x+c=0$. To do this he naively solved for $x$ by rearranging to $x=(4x^3+c)/3$. From here he used the iterative equation $x_{n+1}=(4x_n^3+c)/3$ and it converges quickly even for a relatively bad initial guess. Doing a few test cases shows that this works a lot of the time and for arbitrary polynomials with real roots.

However not all polynomial roots can be calculated this way. For example if I try $x^2-2=x^2+x-x-2=0$ to motivate $x_{n+1}=x_n^2+x_n-2$ it will diverge to $\infty$ even for a guess very close to $\sqrt{2}$.

So the question is given an iterative method of the form $x_{n+1}=p(x_n)$ for some polynomial $p(x)$ what can we say about the radius of convergence? With the condition $\vert p'(L)\vert < 1$ we can assure that $x_{n+1}=(4x_n^3+c)/3$ converges on the interval $(-\frac12 ,\frac12)$ as discussed in the comments however initial values such as $\frac45$ also work well outside that range. Can we say more about the polynomial form specifically?

Comment: Classical condition $|p'(L)|<1$, where $L$ is the limit, but the issue is that you don't know this limit $L$... Therefore you are obliged to do it in a larger "comfort zone"...

Comment: You can rearrange it as $x=\frac{4x^3+c}{3}$, or $x = \frac{3x - c}{x^2}$, or $x = -\frac{c}{4x^2 - 3}$ and each form will lead to a different iteration. All are cases of the well-studied [fixed-point iteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_iteration), though I don't know that you will find much about these forms specifically.

Comment: @dxiv I'm really just interested in the first case since it's a polynomial. I'm hoping that simplification will make the problem more tractable.

Comment: @CyclotomicField Jean Marie's comment gave you the sufficient condition from [Banach fixed-point theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_iteration#Banach_fixed-point_theorem). In your case $|p'(x)| = 4 x^2 \lt 1$ for $|x| \lt 1/2$. Note that $p(-1/2)p(1/2)=c^2 - 1 \lt 0$ if $|c| \lt 1$, so $p(x)$ has at least one root in $(-1/2,1/2)$ and the iteration will converge to one of the roots for any initial value in $(-1/2,1/2)$.

Comment: @dxiv it converges for values outside that region such as $4/5$ so I'm hoping we can say more about it. Tangent line arguments that I've tried haven't been able to explain that. I'll edit the question to make it more clear that the radius of convergence is my primary interest.

Comment: @CyclotomicField Then you are looking for the [basin of attraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attractor#Basins_of_attraction) of each fixed point. I wouldn't call it a radius of convergence, since it's not necessarily an interval on the real axis or a simple connected region in the complex plane, see e.g. the examples [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attractor#Nonlinear_equation_or_system) for the (different, but related) Newton-Raphson iteration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A fixed point $r$ of differentiable function $f$ is attracting if $|f'(r)| < 1$, and repelling if $|f'(r)| > 1$ (it's more complicated if $|f'(r)| = 1$). If it's attracting, the the iteration of $f$ starting at a point sufficiently close to $r$ converges to $r$.

If $(a,b)$ is the immediate basin of attraction for an attracting fixed point $r$ of continuous function $f$, i.e. the largest interval containing $r$ such that iteration of $f$ starting at any point in the
interval converges to $r$.
The following are the possibilities:

1. $f(a) = a$, $f(b) = b$: $a$ and $b$ are fixed points, which can't be attractors.
2. $f(a) = a$, $f(b) = a$: $a$ is a fixed point (and not an attractor), $b$ is mapped to $a$.
3. $f(a) = b$, $f(b) = b$: $b$ is a fixed point (and not an attractor), $a$ is mapped to $b$.
4. $f(a) = b$, $f(b) = a$: $a$ and $b$ form a $2$-cycle (that is not an attractor).
5. $a = -\infty$, $f(b) = b$.
6. $f(a) = a$, $b = +\infty$.
7. $a = -\infty$, $b=+\infty$.

By finding the fixed points and the $2$-cycles, we can determine the basin of attraction: you just take the closest such points (if any) on either side of $r$.  For example, with $p(x) = (4 x^3 - 1/2)/3 $ the fixed points (solutions of $(4 x^3 -1/2)/3 = x$) are approximately $-0.7660444431$,  $-0.1736481777$ and  $0.9396926208$ and there are no real $2$-cycles. The vales of $p'$ at these fixed points are approximately $2.347296355$, $0.1206147585$, and $3.532088886$
respectively.  Thus only the middle one is attracting, and its immediate basin of attraction is the interval between the other two fixed points.